Need help understanding how to decode BCDs and extract specific bits from ARINC 429 data
I do not have much background on this topic; I spent days reading documentation and trying to understand - but I am still completely lost.
I think I understand that the octal number (data label?) tells you the type of the data.
For example, if I have octal number 271, this means this is discrete data and can be BNR and/or BCD. More specifically, I have this data (BCDs):

1059072, when I convert to binary: 0001 0000 0101 1001 0000 0111 0010
2148546816, when I convert to binary: 0010 0001 0100 1000 0101 0100 0110 1000 0001 0110
1064192, when I convert to binary: 0001 0000 0110 0100 0001 1001 0010

I don't know how to map these binary values into the ARINC429 data word to get the correct 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th bit. Bits 9-10 are SDI, bits 22-29 are defined as spares (and so I think they are set to 0), 30-31 are SSM and 32 is parity.
So if bits 22-29 are defined as spares, I assume that this means the meaningful data exists in bits 11-21 of ARINC 429 data word, and the binary values above should be mapped into those. The problem is I have no idea how to map them, despite searching everywhere. I know that ARINC 429 bits are from MSB-LSB, so I know this should be taken into account when mapping by starting from the right side of the binary values, but the problem is I have no idea how to map them to correctly "fit" this range. Apparently the 17th-20th bits should be 0, but no matter how much I try I am not getting that.
To clarify, my issue is not what the bits signify, as this is clarified in the documentation I have. My issue is how does one fit a BCD into the appropriate ARINC429 format? For example, if a BCD is 40-bits in binary form, how does that even fit into ARINC 429 format in the "data field" portion, specifically, bits 11-21 (since 22-29 are spares and unused)? 

That's a lot of unknowns, does reading this (and this answer) help clarify and reduce the scope of what is not clear?

The discrete data is going to be specific to the equipment you're receiving data from, there isn't a standard that says these bits mean this for label 271. You'll need to look at the documentation/ICD for the equipment you are receiving data from.

I have the documentation which says what the bits mean for this label, but the problem is I need to fit the binary values into the ARINC 429 format to determine whether bit 17 is 1 or 0, bit 18, 19, etc., and I don't know how to do that. For example, 1059072 gives 28 bits in binary form, but how can I convert this into ARINC 429 format by fitting it into bits 11-21  where I know the meaningful data is stored? I don't even know if this makes sense because of how little understanding I have, but I really don't understand how a 28-bit or 40-bit digit would fit into ARINC 429

If the label is discrete data, why are you trying to decode the value as a BCD number? The largest BCD number you can fit in the data field is 79999. It looks like the values you have provided are maybe provided by some tool rather than the raw 32 bit ARINC word.

Okay now that makes more sense as to why can't be mapped to fit into the data field. I'm sorry it's because when I read documentation I misunderstood that discrete data can be BNR or BCD, so I assumed from the number I have that it has to be BCD since it is not BNR. But now that you are saying the raw data values I have might be something completely different, then I seem to be on the completely wrong path anyway

Hi Anon, welcome on aviation.stackexchange.com. The ARINC 429 format is very aviation specific and thus considered on-topic. But then you are mapping integer values to binary representations in 3½ bytes, 5 bytes and 3½ bytes. Somehow I have the feeling this ends up in giving a generic course on binary data handling, rather than on aviation-specific formats. I think you need to start by understanding binary formats and bit shifting in general before diving in to ARINC. At least explain us how you are capturing this data, because it look like the tool chain may affect the outcome

Thank you. I really don't know, I received this raw test data which shows 1059072, 2148546816, 1064192. I was not given any further information regarding the format, I was just told it is hexadecimal, which I am not even sure if it is. This is a very frustrating task for me as it is not my specialty in any way, and I am expected to convert it to ARINC429 format and find bits 17-20.

I'm going to work off of the assumption that the values you have (1059072, 2148546816, 1064192) are the decimal representations of the raw 32 bit words received.
   1059072 => 00102900h == 00000000 00010000 00101001 00000000b
2148546816 => 80103900h == 10000000 00010000 00111001 00000000b
   1064192 => 00103D00h == 00000000 00010000 00111101 00000000b

Assuming the label has been zeroed out, and the hex value represents the entire label, the value 1064192 probably corresponds to the following layout.

Looks like discrete bits 21, 14, 13, 12, and 11 are set to me.

Thank you, I just wanted to let you know that your response solved the issue!

As stated in the comments section, the largest value in the data field of an ARINC 429 word with BCD is 79999. However, you could use the Williamsburg/Buckhorn protocol, which is basically an improvement to the ARINC 429 protocol, in order to be able to transmit more than 19 bits of data.
This is a bidirectional system (2 x ARINC 429), and the transfer unit is a "File". The file is divided into LDUs (Link Data Units), which are groups of 32-bit (ARINC 429) words. Files can include up to 255 words. Consequently, within LDUs, you can transmit information packages that exceed the nominal capacity of ARINC 429 words.
The Williamsburg/Buckhorn protocol operates as follows:
· First, there is the Handshake, where an RTS (Ready to Serve) word is transmitted, and the receiver replies with a CTS (Clear to Serve) word, allowing the transmission of the file.
· To begin the transmission of each file, an SOT (Start of Transmission) word is transmitted, indicating that a file is about to be transmitted. It includes information about the number of words within the LDU and the LDU number within the file.
· Then, each word within the LDU is transmitted until the end. Once all are sent, an EOT (End of Transmission) word is transmitted, indicating the LDU is completely sent. It also includes a CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check) error-detecting code.
· An ACK is sent by the receiver.

As @selectstriker2 notes in comments, the largest value you can fit in the field as BCD is 79999. From a tutorial on the format (p. 14)

"Up to 5 subfields can be utilized to provide 5 binary values, with the
Most Significant subfield containing only 3 data field bits (for a maximum binary value of 7). If the Most Significant digit is greater than 7, bits 27-29 are padded with zeros and the second subfield becomes the Most Significant digit allowing 4 binary values instead of 5 to be represented."

The format is deliberately pretty flexible, allowing for BCD, binary, and a mix of the two (or other uses entirely for the field). See pages 13-15 of the tutorial linked above for different options.
I don't think I'm able to answer the question as to how to represent a number larger than 79999 in this format, but given the discussion in the comments above I'm not sure that's needed.

One function of ARINC429 messages that I have seen before is that of "Member System Identification" where a specific unit reports the serial numbers, software identifiers etc as part of a "stream" of ARINC429 words.
In each message 2 bytes of data is sent along with an index starting at 0.
For each subsequent 2 bytes of data sent the index is incremented by 1 and will restart at 0 when the sequence starts again.
For your BCD problem you could send two digits each message and similar to the scheme outlined already, use an index field to indicate what position within the BCD value these two digits represent.
If you want to send 123456, the messages would be
BCD1: 1 BCD2: 2 Index:0
BCD1: 3 BCD2: 4 Index:1
BCD1: 5 BCD2: 6 Index:2

Then starting again with
BCD1: 1 BCD2: 2 Index:0

